# gurobi からpyomoへの変換

Tags: python, python3, pandas, アルゴリズム, データ構造

pythonでgurobiからpyomoへ二次制約付き問題であるため、変更したいのですがやり方がわからなくて困っています。

```
from gurobipy import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
from pyomo.environ import SolverFactory
opt = SolverFactory("optimizer", solver_io="python")
opt.solve(model, tee=True)
opt.options['NonConvex'] = 2
```

そのあとに、excelからpandasを用いてデータ挿入を行いました。

```
model=Model("optimizer")
model.params.NonConvex=2
```

と打ち、gurobiのプログラムを実行しました。
エラーメッセージが

```
untimeError: Attempting to use an unavailable solver.

The SolverFactory was unable to create the solver "optimizer"
and returned an UnknownSolver object.  This error is raised at the point
where the UnknownSolver object was used as if it were valid (by calling
method "solve").

The original solver was created with the following parameters:
    executable: optimizer
    solver_io: python
    type: optimizer
    _args: ()
    options: {}
```

https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_models.html?highlight=options#sending-options-to-the-solver
このサイトを参考に、色々と変更しようと思ったのですが、わからないことが多いです。
例えば、

```
results = optimizer.solve(instance, options="threads=4", tee=True)
```

定式化の定数と変数両方とも"optimizer.solveに変更する必要があるのですか?
変更するのは辞書表記だけですか?
int型やlistは変更する必要ないですか？
また、すべて()の中はinstanceと変更すればいいのですか？

```
s={(1:2,2:3,3:5,4:5)}
d={(1,1):1(1,2):2(1:3):3(1:4):4
  (1,1):3(1,2):4(1:3):5(1:4):6}
```

上のs,dだとどう変更すればいいですか？
"options="=dict名＝dict数"
あと付け加えるべきことはありますか？
例えば、制約式や目的関数などあれば教えてください。
初心者なので出来るだけ詳しく教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 0):

ソースコードにpyomoで対応可能なgurobiのオプション一覧が記載してありますが、「"NonConvex"」はそこに記載されていないので、設定できないと思われます。

https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/2e57707a4bd0aab98df7cb9b0c78e984013fac62/pyomo/solvers/plugins/solvers/gurobi_direct.py

```
    # Options accepted by gurobi (case insensitive):
    # ['Cutoff', 'IterationLimit', 'NodeLimit', 'SolutionLimit', 'TimeLimit',
    #  'FeasibilityTol', 'IntFeasTol', 'MarkowitzTol', 'MIPGap', 'MIPGapAbs',
    #  'OptimalityTol', 'PSDTol', 'Method', 'PerturbValue', 'ObjScale', 'ScaleFlag',
    #  'SimplexPricing', 'Quad', 'NormAdjust', 'BarIterLimit', 'BarConvTol',
    #  'BarCorrectors', 'BarOrder', 'Crossover', 'CrossoverBasis', 'BranchDir',
    #  'Heuristics', 'MinRelNodes', 'MIPFocus', 'NodefileStart', 'NodefileDir',
    #  'NodeMethod', 'PumpPasses', 'RINS', 'SolutionNumber', 'SubMIPNodes', 'Symmetry',
    #  'VarBranch', 'Cuts', 'CutPasses', 'CliqueCuts', 'CoverCuts', 'CutAggPasses',
    #  'FlowCoverCuts', 'FlowPathCuts', 'GomoryPasses', 'GUBCoverCuts', 'ImpliedCuts',
    #  'MIPSepCuts', 'MIRCuts', 'NetworkCuts', 'SubMIPCuts', 'ZeroHalfCuts', 'ModKCuts',
    #  'Aggregate', 'AggFill', 'PreDual', 'DisplayInterval', 'IISMethod', 'InfUnbdInfo',
    #  'LogFile', 'PreCrush', 'PreDepRow', 'PreMIQPMethod', 'PrePasses', 'Presolve',
    #  'ResultFile', 'ImproveStartTime', 'ImproveStartGap', 'Threads', 'Dummy', 'OutputFlag']
```